# Constructor injection to a class consisting of only static methods?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static

I am working on an API which interface with a proprietary piece of hardware. In this API, I have constructed a utility class (for the sake of this post let's call it `B`), consisting of only `static` methods. Most of these methods depend on another class for communicating with the hardware, let's call this `A`. I am currently a little unsure how to design the dependency of `B` on `A` as I cannot instantiate `B` and inject the dependency using constructor injection. From a design perspective, what is the best way to model this behavior?

For a little more hands-on description, here is what I am trying to achieve. Let's say `A` has declarations of certain other classes like so

```
class A
{
   private HardwareCommunicator communicator;
   private ModelLoader modelLoader; 

   public HardwareCommunicator getCommunicator()
   {
      return communicator;
   }

   public ModelLoader getModelLoader()
   {
      return modelLoader;
   }

}
```

And `B` then has `static` methods like so, which seek to use some of the members declared in `A`

```
class B
{
   public static PerformOperation()
   {
      AnotherClass c = new AnotherClass();
      c.someMethod(someValue, hardwareCommunicator.getCommunicator()); // Needs reference

   } 
}
```

Obviously, `B` needs a reference to `A`, so I am currently fiddling with passing the dependency as an argument to the method, like this:

```
class B
{
   public static PerformOperation(HardwareCommunicator communicator) // Passed as argument
   {
      AnotherClass c = new AnotherClass();
      c.someMethod(someValue, communicator.doSomething()); // OK, so far so good
   }
}
```

Now I run into the problem that I sometimes need *more* dependecies than just the `communicator` in `B`, e.g. in another `static` method in `B` I might need  both the `HardwareCommunicator` and the `ModelLoader`

```
class B
{
   public static SomeOtherOperation(HardwareCommunicator communicator)
   {
      AnotherClass c = new AnotherClass();
      c.SomeMethod(someValue, communicator.doSomething(), 
                              ModelLoader.getModelLoader()); // Missing reference
   }
}
```

OK, so I *could* just pass this as a parameter as well, but now I am thinking I have an architectural problem. I should (shouldn't I?) be able to just go

```
class B
{
    public static SomeOtherOperation()
    {
       AnotherClass c = new AnotherClass();
       c.someMethod(someValue, instanceOfA.getCommunicator(),
                               instanceOfA.getModelLoader());
    }
}
```

Without being able to call a constructor on `B` and pass in an instance of `A` I obviously can't achieve this behavior.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't you just initialize an instance of `A` as a compile-time constant member of `B` and reference it from there? If the `A` fields will change at each invocation, then you could probably just require an instance of `A` as parameter to your method invocations and get its fields from there.

Comment: Why does `B` only provide static methods?

Comment: @Mena Thank you for the comment and I apologize for not getting back to you sooner. As far as I know, a compile-time constant must be a primitive type or a String, so I reckon that is not a viable option.

Comment: @AndrewS Like I told Mena, thank you for the comment and apologies for getting back so late. It was dictated to me that this class must only expose static methods but maybe I need to challenge that.

Comment: @kdhansen no worries, and I must admit my statement about "compile-time constant" doesn't make any sense in retrospective. What i meant was that you could use a `final static A` member of `B`.